# How can I compile exported code from Jaxodraw?

Tags: pstricks, axodraw4j

I recently downloaded Jaxodraw for the purpose of constructing Feynman diagrams. My issue is that whenever I export the code in LaTeX I receive the following error:

```
File `pstricks.sty' not found. \usepackage
```

I tried configuring my compiler to use XeLaTeX, but I am still receiving the error.

Here is the code I would like to compile:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{axodraw4j}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{color}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-2in}
\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-2in}

\pagestyle{empty}



\begin{document}

   %%JaxoComment:
   %%JaxoScale{1.0}


\begin{center}
    \fcolorbox{white}{white}{
        \begin{picture}(386,128) (111,-184)
        \SetWidth{2.0}
        \SetColor{Black}
        \GOval(192,-128)(7,7)(0){0.882}
        \SetWidth{1.0}
        \Line[dash,dashsize=0.2](112,-80)(192,-128)
        \Line[dash,dashsize=0.2](112,-176)(192,-128)
        \SetWidth{2.0}
        \GOval(304,-64)(7,7)(0){0.882}
        \GOval(304,-176)(7,7)(0){0.882}
        \GOval(416,-128)(7,7)(0){0.882}
        \SetWidth{1.0}
        \Line[dash,dashsize=0.2](496,-80)(416,-128)
        \Line[dash,dashsize=0.2](496,-176)(416,-128)
        \Bezier(192,-128)(224,-96)(256,-80)(304,-64)%JaxoID:FBez
        \Bezier(192,-128)(240,-160)(272,-176)(304,-176)%JaxoID:FBez
        \Bezier(304,-176)(352,-176)(400,-144)(416,-128)%JaxoID:FBez
        \Bezier(304,-64)(352,-64)(384,-96)(416,-128)%JaxoID:FBez
        \Arc(392,-120)(104.307,147.529,212.471)
        \Arc[clock](216,-120)(104.307,32.471,-32.471)
        \end{picture}
    }
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Any advice on how to resolve this error is appreciated.

Comment: which tex system do you use?

Comment: I use TeXstudio

Comment: that is an editor not a tex system. Do you use texlive or miktex?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's TeX Live.

Comment: in texlive you should be able to install pstricks with `tlmgr install pstricks` (assuming that you have a vanilla texlive, if you have one from a linux distro you should check which tex packages it offers)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `pstricks` for your example. Don't load that package!